# use onclick of an element to jump on next page using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I need to pick all 3 onclick events of these elements and loop through them and get the response / html which it returns using puppeteer. It does AJAX.

All these have same class name but different onclick event data.

Below is the page html-

```
<a type="link" href="#" class="commandLink_TITLE-BLUE" onclick="loadingScreen_Show('contentForm:j_idt1690:j_id77:j_id82');commandLink_ClickHiddenButton(event, 'contentForm:j_idt1690:j_id77:j_id82_commandLink-HIDDEN-BUTTON');">A</a>
<a type="link" href="#" class="commandLink_TITLE-BLUE" onclick="loadingScreen_Show('contentForm:j_idt1691:j_id77:j_id81');commandLink_ClickHiddenButton(event, 'contentForm:j_idt1690:j_id77:j_id82_commandLink-HIDDEN-BUTTON');">B</a>
<a type="link" href="#" class="commandLink_TITLE-BLUE" onclick="loadingScreen_Show('contentForm:j_idt1692:j_id77:j_id89');commandLink_ClickHiddenButton(event, 'contentForm:j_idt1690:j_id77:j_id82_commandLink-HIDDEN-BUTTON');">C</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add to the question a sample of HTML you're working on and a minimal example of your code.

Comment: i have added more details and code in my question...pls have a look..

Comment: What do you mean by `to pick all 3 onclick events`? What happens when you click each of the buttons?